# How to change Object to String?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

problem occurs when concat li  and {menu_link} generate [object Object]

```
var html = ''
if (menuBar.menu_flag_link == 0) {
    var link_menu =
        <NavLink
              to='javascript:;'
            exact>menuBar[i].menu_title</
} else {
        var link_menu =
            <NavLink
                    to="/"
                    exact>menuBar[i].menu_title</NavLink>
}
html += '<li>' + link_menu 
console.log(html) ==> <li>[object Object] // after being executed
console.log(html) ==> <li><a href="/">Dashboard</a> // which are expected
```

Comment: post code same what you have tried so far,

Comment: var link_menu =  is declared inside loop, declare it outside loop

Comment: Use JSON.stringify()

Comment: can't @ShreyKejriwal

Comment: There's `toString()` function for `Object`s.

Comment: yes, it will output [object Object] i mean output is <a href="/"> Dashboard </a>

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON.stringify() like this

```
 var html = ''
    if (menuBar.menu_flag_link == 0) {
        var link_menu =
            <NavLink
                  to='javascript:;'
                exact>menuBar[i].menu_title</
    } else {
            var link_menu =
                <NavLink
                        to="/"
                        exact>menuBar[i].menu_title</NavLink>
    }
    html += '<li>' + JSON.stringify(link_menu)
```

Comment: can not, because NavLink is an object. now is how to turn it into a string?

Comment: you can try like this way html += '<li>' + JSON.stringify(link_menu)

Comment: i mean output this code is <li><a href="/">Dashboard</a>